# Repaint a JPanel from within another JPanel

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

So, I am making a painting program and I have a main `Paint` class which detects mouse input and paints and a `Tools` class which is a toolbar on the left which holds a bunch of tools, like brush size change and shape change. So, I want to add a clear button to the `Tools` class which clears the whole screen. My problem is that the `Paint` class is holding the ArrayList of points which it paints and I can't repaint `Paint` from within `Tools`.

`Paint` class

```
//imports    
public class Paint extends JPanel{
    private ArrayList<Brush> points;
    ...

    public Paint() {
        ...
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics page) {
        ...

        //draws all points in the arraylist
        for (Brush b : points) {
            //paint points
        }
    }
}
```

`Tools` class

```
//imports
public class Tools extends JPanel
{
    private JButton clear;

    public Tools() {
        clear = new JButton("Clear");
        clear.addActionListener(new BrushInput());
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics page) {
        ...
    }
    private class BrushInput implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if (e.getSource() == clear) {
                //clear points arraylist and repaint
            }
        }
    }

}
```

The issue I'm having is that `repaint()` is an instance method and so I can't access `Paint`'s repaint from within `Tools`.

Comment: So, assume that your "tools" have some way of talking to "paint" so it knows how it should be painting, based on what's been selected, why can't you follow the same paradigm?

Comment: Oh the painting is all happening in Paint.

Comment: Yeah, but how does `Paint` know "how" to paint, based on what's been selected on the tool bar? Presumably you must be configuring `Paint` some how?

Comment: It has a MouseListener that detects if the person clicked and repaints whenever the mouse is moved. With my code I would press clear and it would clear but only after I click another time.

Comment: Yeah, but how does it know what brush or color to use? Does the toolbar provide that information? There's a few ways you "might" do it. I'd prefer some kind of controller which was listening to the `Tool` class and then using that information to configure the `Paint` class, which would mean that `Paint` should have a `clear` method which would clear the `ArrayList` and trigger a `repaint`

Comment: Yeah, there are static methods in Paint that Tools uses to change the brush and color.

Comment: *"Yeah, there are static methods in Paint that Tools uses to change the brush and color"* - Well, that's a problem and one you have to resolve before any solution we provide will really work for you. `static` is not a appropriate cross object communication mechanism, instead, you'll want, at the very least, some kind of observer pattern and possibly some kind of MVC to coordinate request from the `Tool` class to the `Paint` class

Comment: So looking online at MVC examples, all the Listener classes are separate. I was taught to make the listener classes nested within the classes (ie. MouseInput nested within Paint to detect painting). Is this bad practice? Now that I think about it, I could have one listener for all of them.

Comment: No, it comes down to needs - If the listener is specialised for a particular component, there's nothing wrong with it been enclosed internally to the class, but there are times that you want to share/reuse the functionality, so you might make it separate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just pass a reference to the `Paint` instance to `Tools`'s constructor. Or, call repaint on the container (`JFrame`, etc.) that contains both of them, which should cause all its children to be repainted.

For example:

```
public class Paint extends JPanel {
    private ArrayList<Brush> points;

    // . . .

    public void clear() {
        points.clear();
        repaint();
    }
}

public class Tools extends JPanel {
    private JButton clear;
    private Paint paint;

    public Tools(Paint paint) {
        this.paint = paint;
        // . . .
    }

    // . . .

    private class BrushInput implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if (e.getSource() == clear) {
                paint.clear();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Code that creates these components:

```
Paint paint = new Paint();
Tools tools = new Tools(paint);
```

Comment: Isn't repaint an instance method though, I have a JFrame which holds both but how would I call it's repaint?

Comment: @L1ghtShadow By passing a reference to it into `Tools` when you construct it.

Comment: @L1ghtShadow: if you call `repaint()` on the JFrame, it should also repaint recursively all its child components.

Comment: Oh nice! Thanks so much.